# Sending SMS(Text) Messages from a .Net Application

Tags: .net, sms, message

I am wondering if anyone has ever set up text messages from a Website, the website is .Net.

The only requirement seems to be, for the enduser not to need to list their provider, only their cell number.

I have researched some third party vendors that charge a few cents per text but would like to avoid this if at all possible.

Is it possible to send an sms message from a .Net application without having a cell phone plugged into the server in some way?

Comment: Options: use a cell phone, use a GPRS modem, use a third-party service.  There's no conceivable other option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all providers have the ability to accept SMS texts via email. I don't see how you are going to get around not knowing the provider - there are some third party sites that do reverse provider lookups but god knows how dodgy those can be.

I do not think there are any SMS Gateways that are free. They are complex and expensive to maintain. :(

Here is a list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways